# React Intl Date Format to get specific date format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, react-intl, intldateformatter

I am using React Intl Date formating API's

https://github.com/formatjs/react-intl/blob/master/docs/API.md#date-formatting-apis

I wanted to have the date in this format

```
August 7, 2019
```

Basically the Intl date does not have the following format. This is what i have tried

```
<FormattedDate
  year: 'numeric',
  day: '2-digit',
  month: 'long',
/>
```

How do i get this format -  `August 7, 2019` format to use in the React Intl Formatted Date API

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
<FormattedDate
  value={new Date()}
  year="numeric"
  month="long"
  day="2-digit"
/>
```